# Can I cross-build electron-forge apps for all platforms?

Tags: build, electron, multiplatform, electron-forge

I'm using electron-forge to build apps for Linux, macOS and Windows. Currently, I can build the macOS distributable natively from macOS, but I need two VMs to build for Linux and Windows.

From each platform VM, I just need to issue the `make` script:

`npm run make`

Is it possible to cross-build for all platforms from a single system? Do I need one specific platform to be able to build for the others as well?

What I want to accomplish is to be able to run a build script that will build distributable files for all supported platforms (namely Linux, macOS and Windows) from a single platform, without the need to manually run VMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using macOS you can build for all 3 platforms.
You can try [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build) or [electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager)

Here's a simple command to generate distributables for all 3 platforms using electron-builder

`electron-builder -mwl`

Comment: As I read today in the respective descriptions, both tools mentioned seem to be cross-platform (Linux, macOS, Windows), so this answer seems unnecessarily restrictive. Has the functionality been extended since then, or am I missing an important detail?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `npm run make` it will generate  platforms pecific distributables (installers, distribution packages, etc.) but by default it can only generate distributables for your current platform .

Checkout your package.json for more platform specific targets like dmg,zip for Macos